# Catching exception/error in database transaction

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, joomla-api, error-handling, database

I am using the following way in joomla 2.5 and 3 to execute database query -

```
$database = JFactory::getDBO();
$database->setQuery
$database->execute();
```

but how do I catch errors/exceptions if the query fails for any reasons as `$database->getErrorNum()` is deprecated?

Answer (score 13):

JError has been deprecated in J3.x, in favour of PHP exceptions, as it [intermixed 2 different programming concepts](http://docs.joomla.org/Exceptions_and_Logging_in_Joomla_1.7_and_Joomla_Platform_11.1): logging and error handling (the logging side has now been implemented as [JLog](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_JLog)).

For your exact case, you can wrap your code in a try / catch block to get the error, as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967904/joomla-jdatabasegeterrornum-is-deprecated-use-exception-handling-instead):

```
try {
    ...
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadResult();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Note that `$database->execute()` is stated to [NOT work in J2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase). You should use `$database->query()` if you need an equivalent.

In Joomla 2.5 and 3.x the [`JDatabase` object methods](http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase#The_Query) `updateRecord()` and `insertRecord()` also throw errors you can catch if they fail:

```
try {
    JFactory::getDbo()->updateObject('#_table_name', $data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //...handle the exception
}
```

If you're developing for Joomla 3.x only, you can also use a try catch block with [SQL transactions](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_transactions_in_Joomla) to get the error details:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

try {
    $db->transactionStart();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $values = array($db->quote('TEST_CONSTANT'), $db->quote('Custom'), $db->quote('/path/to/translation.ini'));

    $query->insert($db->quoteName('#__overrider'));
    $query->columns($db->quoteName(array('constant', 'string', 'file')));
    $query->values(implode(',',$values));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->execute();

    $db->transactionCommit();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // catch any database errors.
    $db->transactionRollback();
    JErrorPage::render($e);
}
```

Comment: in my joomla 2.5.11 $database->execute(); works fine as i am making single component for joomla 2.5 and 3. But your first try-catch block with execute() not works in 2.5.11. As you said Jdatabase object methods only works 2.5 and 3.1 so not gonna use it.So what other methods available to implement this and compatible with both J 2.5 and 3 versions??.

Comment: Huh, weird, the docs seem to state that ->execute() doesn't work in 2.5. Will edit. JDatabase object methods should work in all J3.X versions

Comment: "But your first try-catch block with execute() not works in 2.5.11"... what error do you get, if any?

Comment: I did not check message but i put a return false; there but it's not returning false for sure so is control not entering in catch block in my 2.5.11 site.

Comment: Could you enable error reporting in Global Configuration To see if PHP is generating any errors.

Comment: yes i even set error reporting to maximum and although i get various errors but non of them regarding something wrong in query in my component(i deliberately made query not to be successful by removing a quote to get errors).

Comment: Could you post the full code on Pastebin or something similar and the error information that you do have?

Comment: For reference on the `$db->execute();` piece, that method was backported into 2.5.5.  So if you need to support 2.5 and 3.x in a single code base, my suggestion is to only support 2.5.6+ (remember the issues with 2.5.5) and you can keep your code fairly clean.  Supporting the older 2.5 releases is possible but has a higher maintenance cost.

Comment: It's look like trying to get exception without execute() method not working too as following code in my modal `try {
    ... $this->_data = $database->loadObject();  
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}`i debugged and saw that control not entering in catch block!.So now what's wrong?

Comment: Could you post your full code on Pastebin so I can test?

Comment: I am using Joomla 2.5.28; $db->execute() runs, but it does not throw error when there is a sql query error. It just keeps zipping by. Is there any other way to detect errors?

Comment: Well, if ($db->getErrorNum()) die($db->stderr()); works...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally install pecl then extend the appropriate JDatabase* class and override JFactory::getDbo() with an implementation of the below to eliminate the need for a squillion code updates to wrap every critical db query in try catch statements.

Next best thing for me is the below support for the old way and the new way:

Include this somewhere

```
class jDbUtils
{
    protected static $dbErrorMessage = '';

    public static function stupidJ3CatchDatabaseExecute($db, $cmd, $report = false) {
        self::$dbErrorMessage = '';
        try {
            $res = $db->$cmd();
            // legacy db error support
            if (method_exists($db, 'getErrorNum') && $db->getErrorNum())
                throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());
            return $res;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            self::$dbErrorMessage = $e->getMessage();
            if ($report)
                self::reportIfDbError();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function reportIfDbError()
    {
        if (self::$dbErrorMessage) {
            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(self::$dbErrorMessage, 'error');
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this

```
function someDbInteraction(){
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $db->setQuery('SELECT no_such_col FROM no_such_table LIMIT 1');
    $res = jDbUtils::stupidJ3CatchDatabaseExecute($db, 'loadResult');
    if (jDbUtils::reportIfDbError())
        return false;
    // do more processing
    return $res;
}
```